# DEPRECATION WARNING: ActionView::Base in rails 6.0 for sanitize

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

I am getting a deprecation warning:

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: ActionView::Base instances should be constructed with a lookup context, assignments, and a controller. (called from <top (required)> at /Users/johndel/projects/collaboraate/backend/config/environment.rb:5)
```

On my attempt to update to rails 6. The app is using the following code:
`ActionView::Base.full_sanitizer.sanitize(event.description)`, what is the right way now to replace this?

Comment: The code is `Rails.application.initialize!` as in most rails apps. The problem which needs to be change is the code I wrote above (`ActionView::Base.full_sanitizer.sanitize(event.description)`) though which needs to be change on something else.

Comment: This code needs to be inside a model.